# can't select text after making input only numeric

Tags: jquery, html, constraints, numeric

This problem seems to happen in webkit based browsers (chrome and safari). Not Firefox.

After constraining certain input fields to only numerics and a `:` I'm no longer able to select the text or move the cursor to the left with the arrow keys. The input gets deselected or in case of the cursor: it's moved to the end of the input. (I am able to place the cursor somewhere in the string by clicking there with my mouse)

Code used:

```
$('#from, #to, #rate, #break').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9:\.]/g,'');
});
```

Example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/EKYBr/

Did I do something wrong? Is it a negative side effect I can't do anything about? Or is there a way to make textselection and cursor movement possible?

Comment: What browser and version are you using? I had no problems with Firefox.

Comment: Oops forgot to mention it's only on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

When you overwrite the value, the caret automatically goes the end of the input.

What you need to do is overwrite the value, only if needed. i.e. something like:

```
$('#from, #to, #rate, #break').keyup(function () { 
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37:
        case 38:     
        case 39:
        case 40: break;
        default: this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9:\.]/g,'');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EKYBr/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your overwrite the value everytime. you better should get the key and don't let the user input it.

```
$('#time').keydown(function (event) {
        // 48-56 => 0-9 | 58 = ":"
        if((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 56) or event.keyCode != 58)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKYBr/2/)